# create and call a route from a processor in camel

Tags: java, apache-camel

I googled out but I could not find any single insight about the problem.
which is as follows

1. Get a payload from JMS queue.
2. get the details of the FTP server from the payload and archive all the files to a different location.
3. Do some Processing on the payload data and store it as a text files on the local system.

As it can be seen that the 2nd step is nothing but starting a different route if I am not mistaken. I thought of adding a processor which would start a route to consume all the files from the ftp location and producing it to some endpoint. This step it has to do nothing with the exchange which  I receive from the first step. So is there  a way we can implement this functionality.

I have completed 1st and 3rd step as it is easy and there are many examples all over the internet.

If you have come across this situation, please guide me.

Comment: How do you get the details of the ftp server from the payload? Seems strange.

Answer (score 0):

Well, not sure how you get the ftp details from the payload but why not do it like this.

1. Get the ftp connection and other details and store it in the exchange headers.
2. Disable autostart on the ftp route.
3. Based on some condition on the first route then you start the second route which fetches the ftp details from the exchange header and fetches all the files. So once you completed the first route, only then do you allow the second route to start. With route here I mean a standalone route and not a processor or anything like that.

See here:
http://camel.apache.org/configuring-route-startup-ordering-and-autostartup.html